# How to invoke an existing IDE action in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea

I've written a plugin that adds a group to the "new file" menu, and I want my action to launch a specific file template. From what I understand the action is called "NewFromTemplate", but I've encoutered two problems:

1. How to invoke an already existing action, in this case `NewFromTemplate`?
2. How to pass arguments to it, since I want it to create a file from a specific template.

The best I've come up with it is:

```
ActionManager am = ActionManager.getInstance();
AnAction ftAction = am.getAction("NewFromTemplate");
ActionManager.getInstance().tryToExecute(
        ftAction, 
        ActionCommand.getInputEvent("NewFromTemplate"), 
        null, 
        ActionPlaces.UNKNOWN, 
        true);
```

But it doesn't seem to open anything - the code executes but no new window is opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I've done it (just an example using a hardcoded Template name to show the required methods)

```
public class FooAction extends AnAction {

public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
    FileTemplateManager fileTemplateManager = FileTemplateManager.getInstance();
    FileTemplate[] templates = fileTemplateManager.getAllTemplates();

    for(FileTemplate ft : templates){

        if(ft.getName().equals("Singleton")){
            AnAction action = new CreateFromTemplateAction(ft);
            action.actionPerformed(e);
        }


    }

}
```

}

Comment: Are you still working on the project? Do you still prefer using "AnAction"? I have a similar requirement, and I'm using "CreateFileFromTemplateAction". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69032496/how-to-create-sub-menu-for-file-templates-in-intellij-idea-plugin-devkit?noredirect=1#comment122045115_69032496